# How can I wait for a git clone to finish in GitPython

Tags: python, synchronous, gitpython

I am cloning from local network using the code below:

```
_g = cmd.Git(clone_path)
path = os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(path))
path = path.replace('\\', '/')
_g.clone("-o" + host,
    "http://" + host + ':8002' + '/' + path + '/' + '.git',
    os.path.join(clone_path, repo))
```

Now I need to wait for the clone operation to copmplete (succesfully) to proceed. How am I to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git-python, all direct git calls like `repo.git.clone()` are synchronous. There is the option to run it asynchronously using the `as_process` flag. Thus, calling `repo.git.clone(..., as_process=True)` returns a `subprocess.Popen` instance which must be handled accordingly. In the most simple case, you would call `communicate()` on it to receive its entire output.

Doing so is usually never needed nor recommended, as git-python provides higher level methods to get the common operation done more conveniently.

If you desire to simplify your code, you could use a higher-level operation, such as this one:

```
import git
r = git.Repo.clone_from(your_url, checkout_path, origin=host)
```

`r` is a `Repo` instance, which is your handle to all git-related operations. The documentation for it [is on readthedocs](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#meet-the-repo-type).

Comment: Is `git.Repo.clone_from()` synchronous ?

Comment: Yes, everything in gitpython is.

Comment: Can you link me to the docs stating this ? What I used definitely wasn't synchronous - synchronous means _blocking till the method returns_ in this context - maybe you confuse this with threads

Comment: I don't think I am confusing this - all I can say it that it is supposed to be synchronous, and [the code](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/repo/base.py#L826) seems to support this statement as well. 'clone_from' returns a Repo instance, which is ready to go, not a future or promise of some sort.

Comment: Aha - so you mean that the lower level operation is not synchronous while the higher level is - since you are a gitPython dev I accept your answer and will get back to you when I get round to testing. Btw - I think this is a wrong design decision :( To be much more intuitive to git (as opposed to svn and whatnot) users the `git` object should behave as the command line - so `cmd.Git().clone()` should be synchronous.

Comment: I have updated my answer to tell a little more about the `Git` command.

Comment: Thanks for the input - appreciated ;). So `cmd.Git(clone_path).clone()` was indeed asynchronous right (09/2014) ? As for the API - it should be: `g = Git('/path/to/repo')` then `g.clone(), g.commit()` etc - this repo idea is quite ungit, just complicates things and makes learning curve steeper

Comment: Interesting - maybe you want to write a shell script then. The intended use of `Git` is in the 5% of the use-cases which have no 'pythonic' implementation yet. As `Git` is stable for a long time now, I'd recommend just using its code in your project, and kill one dependency.

Comment: Thanks - so finally was `cmd.Git(clone_path).clone()` indeed asynchronous - right ? Please edit your answer to make this clear

Comment: No, it's synchronous. which version of GitPython are you using ?

Comment: The one that was out on september 2014